# How do I theme the user register page?

Tags: theming, 8

In Drupal 7, we can use a template file like page--user--register.tpl.php, or we can register our own template file.

How we can do it in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar in D8. Copy page.html.twig from core or base theme and put it into the template directory of your theme.

Rename it like this:

```
page--user--register.html.twig
```

Comment: How do I access the user account fields in this template. I want to access the email, picture and some other fields that I have added to the Drupal user account ?